# ansible: found a duplicate dict key (prompt)

Tags: ansible, command, prompt

I am trying to backup a cisco switch config to tftp with ansible.

I am an ansible newbie but managed simple one liners to get and set options in a switch. The backup to tftp command will not work for now.

apparently the command parameters are stored in a python dictionary and when i try to use prompt: and answer: options twice in one command i get an error.

`[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from backup-cisco-tftp.yml, line 11, column 9, found a duplicate dict key (prompt). Using last defined value only.`

at the task it says:

`fatal: [SW3]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "argument commands is of type <type 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list: <type 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list"}`

The code is:

```
      gather_facts: false
      connection: network_cli
      tasks:
      - name: backup to tftp
        ios_command:
          commands:
            command: "copy running-config tftp:"
            prompt: "remote host"
            answer: "1.5.1.2"
            prompt: "filename"
            answer: "backup-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

I guess there must be a way to wait for text and add a response twice?

Thanks in advance

Wouter

Comment: Please improve question. 
Try adding following things :
What you are trying to achieve ?
Where you are facing problem?

Comment: That's is in there or not? Trying to backup a cisco config to tftp. And problem is i can't use prompt/answer twice in one command.

Comment: Add sample command. Keep error statements under code blocks.
Make question title more clear (e.g. How do I specify two options in single command in ansible ?)
Add more tags (e.g. cisco, tftp)
All these make your question reach to better audience.

Comment: added code blocks. 
cisco or tftp is not the problem itself in my opinion so I thought i made it as clear as possible to stick to the problem. Other people could face the same issue while having another goal. Isn't it?
I am a starter on this platform when it comes to posting so correct me when I make the wrong decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as below

```
    - name: play
      hosts: effe
      gather_facts: false
      connection: network_cli
      tasks:
      - name: backup to tftp
        cli_command:
         command: "copy running-config tftp:"
         check_all: True
         prompt: 
          - "remote host"
          - "filename"
         answer: 
          - "1.5.1.2"
          - "backup-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Comment: parameters are looking good (with -vvvv) but timeout. 
fatal: [SW3]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "timeout value 30 seconds reached while trying to send command: copy running-config tftp:"

Comment: tried with []? at end and with wildcards. Debug doesn't say where exactly de timeout is.
prompt:
        - "Address or name of remote host.*"
        - "Destination filename.*"

Comment: Works !!  I added: check_all: True as read in the module examples and then this example works.  
Not sure if  i understand why because this option says to use all the prompts and answers in order, which is fine, but when false i read it as if it grabs the prompt it sees and gives the answer. 
Main thing is it works. Thanks smily !!

Answer (score 0):

The only approach that worked for me was to use the part of the prompt that resides within []. My mistake was that I specified full prompt like "Host name or IP address (control-c to abort): [2.2.2.2]?" and I had to pick just "[2.2.2.2]".

```
---
 - name: run commands that require answering a prompt
   hosts: ios_xr_routers:1.1.1.1
   gather_facts: no
   connection: network_cli
   vars:
     ansible_network_os: ios


   tasks:
   - name: backup
     cli_command:
      command: "copy running-config tftp://2.2.2.2/test vrf MGMT"
      check_all: True
      prompt:
       - "[2.2.2.2;MGMT]"
       - "[/test]"
      answer:
       - "2.2.2.2"
       - "test"
```